# ¿Como enviar una Variable mediante redirect a una vista? Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando pasar un mensaje de confirmacion de evento(en este caso guardado)

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public function postcrear_categoria(create_categoria_request $request){

    $categoria = categoria::create([
        'CA_nombre' => $request->input('name'),
    ]);

    $message = 'Categoria Guardada';
    return redirect('/home')->with('message',$message);
}
```

pero en la vista no llega la variable

asi la implemento en la vista

```
@isset($message)
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        {{ $message }}
    </div>   
@endisset
```

¿Por qué hago un redirect y una view?

Resulta que en la vista de esa ruta tengo una tabla la cual envia datos para una tabla y si coloco esa vista tendria que rendundar codigo para pedir esos datos , ya que , necesito confirmar la creacion , actualizacion y eliminacion de varios modelos diferentes

aqui el codigo de la ruta /home

```
public function gethome(){
    $producto = producto::paginate(15);
    return view('home',[
        'productos' => $producto,
    ]);
}
```

PD: no se requiere autentificacion de administrador ni loggin para modificar los modelos , ya que , el proyecto no lo requiere

Comment: Yo envio las variables de la siguiente forma `return redirect()->route('home')->with($message);`, en tu caso seria quitar el `'message'` de tu `with()`, asi no te deveria dar problemas y llegar tu varible a la vista

Comment: no llega la variable a la vista ... eh leido muchos problemas y nada , no quiero solucionar con redundar codigo :s

Comment: No hace falta q indiques q la pregunta esta resuelta. Simplemente con marcar una opción correcta como hiciste anteriormente, esta bien.

Comment: No es válido poner SOLUCIONADO no hagas eso

Comment: lo siento :s , nuevo en la comunidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para comprobar los flash datas en una redirección conviene más usar if

```
@if(session('message'))
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    {{ $message }}
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: no me sirvio :C

Comment: Lo acabo de probar en mi proyecto y funciona perfectamente de hecho viene en la doc de laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data quizas tienes errores de validación y por eso no ves el mensaje, por que de hecho usando isset devuelve un pantallazo negro. Revisa que si esté redireccionando en esa parte de tu script y no antes.

Comment: :s acabo de volver a inter y nada

Comment: listo ya se resolvio si era la solucion pero tenia un error de escritura

Comment: Que bueno que encontraste el error :)